# ssh into compute instance in OCI - permission denied

Tags: ssh, terraform, instance, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I got an image (image OCID) that was created by a colleague of mine, that contains non-empty `.ssh/authorized_keys` for `opc` , `ubuntu` and another custom user. When I  create an instance based on that image and pass a public key, I *almost-always get 'permission denied' when trying `ssh ubuntu@instance_public_IP` (I am using ssh-agent and ssh-add to manage private keys on my side, and have appropriate key added).

I did the following troubleshooting so far:

1. I created an instances both via oci website and terraform based on "Canonical Ubuntu" and passed my public key there - ssh connection successful
2. I repeatedly destroyed and rebuilt the instances above to check if there is some kind of cashing going on - ssh works fine
3. I created a custom image based on an instance running "Canonical Ubuntu" with `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` filled with outdated keys to check if preexisting keys interfere with the deployment process - ssh works fine
4. I created an instance based on untouched image supplied by my colleague **without** passing any extra keys - he can ssh
5. I created an instance based on the image above and passed extra key - 90% of the time I can not ssh into it, my colleague can ssh in using his keys and sees my public key in `authorized_keys` after all his preexisting keys, I can not ssh in except the 10% of cases, but I have no idea why it works, and rebooting the instance always shuts me off
6. I created an instance as above, got my colleague to ssh in, then removed `authorized_keys` from `ubuntu` user, created custom image called 'clean-keys` based on a running instance, created instance based on 'clean-keys' and passed my key - ssh doesn't work
7. Did as above, but removed `authorized_keys` from all users - ssh doesn't work

The behavior described above is the same regardless if the instance is created by the website or terraform.

The image in question contains fully configured environment that I need to be able to deploy automatically. The ssh connection is needed to set off some processes.

I'm out of ideas.

When building instances using terraform I pass my public key via

```
    metadata = {
        ssh_authorized_keys = file(var.ssh_public_key_path)
        }
```

The keys match

Comment: w.r.t  'clean-keys'  image have you checked the permissions for ubuntu user to access the newly uploaded key? also posting the ssh output with the verbose flag -v you may get some insight

Answer (score 0):

You could try the instance console connection to remote into the machine and figure out what is going on https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/References/serialconsole.htm

See the section on "To boot into maintenance mode"